# Hash maps producing random effects in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently developing a solution in matlab that requires the use of Hash Maps as a way to generate data structures that can be scaled (not really important in terms of my question).

I have a hashmap defined as

```
var_hash = containers.Map;
new_array = arr0;
%var_hash = {'foo':arr1,'baz':arr2,'bar':arr3}
var_hash_keys = var_hash.keys();
for i = 1:length(var_hash_keys);
    key = var_hash_keys{i};
    new_array = new_array + var_hash(key);
end
```

Now the issue I seem to have is that simply adding the arrays

```
arr0 + arr1 + arr2 + arr3 != new_array
```

Is this a serious mistake on my end i.e. bad programming, or is there something fishy going on?

Though, I have moved past this and did it in a brute force way, given the relatively few arrays to add, but I would like to understand what i have done wrong.

Comment: Just a detail - but I don't think that `containers.Map` states that it is a *hash* map; rather, it is simply an associative container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your problem is here - but I'm going to assume that what you're observing is simply that *floating-point* addition is not precisely associative because of intermediate round-off. From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html :

> Another grey area concerns the interpretation of parentheses. Due to roundoff errors, the associative laws of algebra do not necessarily hold for floating-point numbers. For example, the expression (x+y)+z has a totally different answer than x+(y+z) when x = 10^{30}, y = -10^{30} and z = 1 (it is 1 in the former case, 0 in the latter). The importance of preserving parentheses cannot be overemphasized.

Comment: +1 for the information of the association may be the cause. I will be able to check when back at the desk if this is indeed the case. The elements of the arrays are not of the order for that to be the issue as you stated above (but it may still be an issue for 10^10). Also sorry for the lack of further information. I did check for Low value elements and it seemed to be ok with the method above..so hopefully this is the issue. I will accept if this answer solves my problem.

Comment: That was indeed the issue! Thank you for showing me this unusual behavior. So we can reduce the magnitude for this to arrays where the max is of the order 10^7 (at least for me). Cheers.